# Check real path or content of job/task

Tags: batch-file

is it possible to check the contents of a job or which program it will start using a batch file?

for example, I want to check if a task contains iexplore.exe or just .exe (see the real image path)

Is this possible? thanks

Comment: Right click .bat file -> open with -> notepad -> ctrl+f -> type .exe?

Comment: Hi, I don't want to see the contents of a bat file, but create a batch file in which I can check the image path of a job/task. thanks!

Comment: It's still not really clear what you're asking. Could you give a more detailed example?

Comment: @Jeremy, what do you mean by **check the image path of a job/task**?

Comment: if you mean a scheduled task with "job", `schtasks /query /?` should help you.

Comment: Hello all, yes I mean what file is executing a job. So, schtasks suits my needs, but I'm having an issue. I will make a new topic, thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

schtasks seems to do at least partly what I want, but I'm running into some issues.

Posted new topic here:
[Fetch info of scheduled tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995121/fetch-info-of-scheduled-tasks)

thanks!