# Fetch info of scheduled tasks

Tags: batch-file

I earlier posted this question:
[Check real path or content of job/task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34950907/check-real-path-or-content-of-job-task)

This may have been a bit confusing, so I'm rephrasing: what I want is the content, name, description etc. of a task on the system.

For example, I want to know which tasks contain or execute iexplore.exe.

I have used the following command:

```
schtasks /query /fo LIST /v | findstr /i /s "iexplore.exe"
```

This will give me the output:

> Task to Run: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe

But this is insufficient information. Ideally, I want to have listed:
Name, Location, Description

If I use:

```
schtasks /query /v | findstr /i /s "iexplore.exe"
```

I get a whole bunch of output, unsorted and not all relevant (I don't want to know the battery mode etc.)

Is there a way to accomplish the output I'd like (for example:)

> Task to run: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe
>
> Name: Management
>
> Description: Open Management Interface
>
> Location: %userprofile%\desktop\Management.html

Is this possible at all via schtasks? And if not, can I use the **dir** command somehow, in a list format or at least clean output as above?

I would like the output to be piped into a log or text file (as I have some scripts, I can just put it in there).

Thank you!

Comment: Use the CSV option as output.  That way you get all the information you want on one line.

Comment: thanks for your reply squashman! I would like it in a log or text file however, not csv. I'll add it to my post since I forgot. Any idea? Thank you

Comment: You are not understanding.  They only way you are going to be able to accurately get the information you need is to have the query output in a CSV format.

Comment: I get what you mean now, getting to it, thank you!

Comment: This is painful using a batch file (cmd.exe shell script). PowerShell is a much better option. For example: [Use PowerShell to Report on Scheduled Tasks](http://windowsitpro.com/powershell/how-use-powershell-report-scheduled-tasks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDITED** now it handles every occurence of "iexplore.exe"

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "task="
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%a in ('schtasks /query /fo csv /v ^| find /i "iexplore.exe"') do (
  set "task=%%~a"
  schtasks /query /fo list /v /tn "!task!"|findstr /c:"Aufgabenname" /c:"Kommentar" /c:"Starten in" /c:"Auszufhrende Aufgabe"
)
```

NOTE: The names are dependent on the language of the windows installation. Most of your criterias don't exist on my windows, so I used my local names. Please adapt them to your needs.

Comment: Hi Stephan, thanks for your help! When I use your script and even though I replace the criterias, I'm getting: "ERROR: The system cannot find the path specified." any idea? thank you!

Comment: what does `echo -%task%-` say?

Comment: an echo %task% outputs the path of the file (so in this case: C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe)

Comment: @Stephan, would you not have to use the CSV or Table output option to get the correct Task name to use in the final schtasks execution.  I don't see how you can accurately get the task name with the LIST format.

Comment: @Squashman In the first line I get the TaskName (well, the last one, if there are several with the search criteria), with the second line only the entries for this TaskName (`/TN`). However if there is more than one task with this name, you get multiple output, but still in the format, OP desires.

Comment: and besides, `FO CSV` would prevent me from filtering the just four desired criterias.

Comment: @Stephan, going to disagree with you on that. The schtasks command in the FOR /F is just finding the TASK TO RUN line from the LIST output.

Comment: @Squashman ah - now I got you. You are right. I'll rethink that.

Comment: @Stephan, you just need to use the CSV output and get token 2 with a comma as the delimiter.

Comment: Hello Stephan, Squashman, I have tried with piping the output to CSV and combining the scripts, but I'm not getting any output. Not sure what i'm doing wrong.. thanks again!

Comment: @Stephan, why do you think there would be a problem if it is only in the root?

Comment: @Squashman because I like them to be organized and use folders. nevertheless - I don't know why, but now it works. Thank you for your input. Jeremy: please see my edit. "Should" work now.

Comment: Thank you Squashman for the feedback and Stephan for your work! It's working perfectly now.

FYI, the names in English are: /c:"TaskName" /c:"Run Time" /c:"Comment" /c:"Run as" /c:"Task To Run" 

/c:"Description"

Comment: @Stephan , Squashman , I've been running some more test and I'm having a weird issue: when I run this batch file as Administrator, I'm not getting any output (right-click > Run as Admin). When I'm executing normally, I get output. Any idea? Ideally it must work the former way, as it's part of a script that runs with permissions (admin manifest). Thanks!

Comment: @Jeremy: do you redirect output to a file? Keep in mind, you have a different working directory when you "run as administrator" (`%windir%\system32`).

Comment: @Stephan: Yes I do. I will review and see, maybe I need to change the working dir indeed. Good point, will try and comment in an hour. Thanks again!